# Add the same field multiple times to a display suite node display

Tags: display-suite

So I'm using display suite with a 2-column layout, and my node has an entity reference field (field_journal). I'm already displaying field_journal as a rendered entity in the LH column, but I'd also like to display a different grouping of fields from the linked entity in the RH column.

I was thinking the best way to do that would be to add field_journal *again* to the RH column, but I can't figure out how to duplicate fields in display suite.

Is there some way to add the same field to a node display in 2 different places in the layout? Or can anyone help me with a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using display suite you can use [hook_ds_fields_info](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!ds!ds.api.php/function/hook_ds_fields_info/7) for defining a new display suite field that you can use to clone your existing field.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_ds_fields_info().
 */
function MODULE_ds_fields_info($entity_type) {
  $fields = array();

  $fields['node']['journal_clone'] = array(
    'title' => t('Journal clone'),
    'field_type' => DS_FIELD_TYPE_FUNCTION,
    'function' => 'MODULE_journal_clone',
  );

  if (isset($fields[$entity_type])) {
    return array($entity_type => $fields[$entity_type]);
  }
  return;      
}

/**
 * Render a clone of journal.
 */
function MODULE_journal_clone($field) {
  $build = '';
  if (isset($field['build']['field_journal'])) {
    $build = $field['build']['field_journal'];
  }
  return render($build);
}
```